# Run the function after the effects is done

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I run the function after the effect is done like delaying running the specified function after a certain time? I tried set timeout and it didn't work for me.

Here my Code

```
<script>
    $("#findtext").keyup(function (e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 13)
        {
            explodeEffect();

        }

            $.ajax({
                url: 'resultFindFriend.php',
                type: 'post',
                async: false,
                data: { dataFriend: $(this).val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('.outputfindfriend').html(data);
                }
            },setTimeout(150));

    });

    function explodeEffect() {
        $("#explodesearchresult").toggle("explode");
        setTimeout(1000);
        window.location("http://localhost/index.html");
    };

    $("#buttonfriend").click(function () {
        explodeEffect();
        return false;

    });



</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is doable with jQuery's [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), just add a function as the second argument.

Try this:

```
function explodeEffect() {
  $("#explodesearchresult").toggle(400, function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.location.href = "http://localhost/index.html";
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

This will redirect the page 1 second **after** the explode effect has finished.

Comment: sorry sir but it didnt work for me.. it did not redirect me to the other page after 1 sec

Comment: @rodolfonavalon - This was an issue with my copying and pasting of `window.location`. Try my edited answer.

Comment: Yea I change it to window.location.href = "http://localhost/index.html"; and now it works thank you for your help sir.

Comment: No problem, happy to help. :) I recommend searching jQuery's website for documentation. They have a lot of helpful examples.

Comment: The `toggle` method doesn't accept an animation type as the first parameter. The different overloads are `toggle(duration, complete)`, `toggle(options)`, `toggle(duration, easing, complete)`, and `toggle(showOrHide)`.

Comment: @Ian - Oops, I was just copying the initial code from the question. I have updated this to the default duration value of 400 ms.

Comment: @Aiias Sorry, didn't notice the OP had it. I just wasn't sure if I was missing/forgetting something. Either way, good answer :)